# joomla 3.1 ajax module

Tags: ajax, joomla, module

ok so I have a main horizontal menu that appears on all pages, (company, products, about us) and I want another menu, (vertical accordion on the left side of the page) inside products:

phone

--samsung galaxy s4

--iphone 4

pc

--hp pavilion

--toshiba

and when I clic on any of the sections of the accordion menu the information about each product appears on the right using ajax. I have made the accordion menu as a custom html module and the same with the content that its supposed to appear on the right side (I used modules instead of articles).

Now I'm thinking that its probably better to create another menu for the accordion and that the content should be articles, but I dont know how to make it look like an accordion, and I still need help using ajax to show the content of each product.

the main thing is, I want to use ajax to replace one module for another when I clic on any section of the accordion menu. is there any way to do it, all I could find in google its how to change the main article of the page, for that i have to replace
jdoc:include type="component" and add an event with the url but that replaces everything and I just want to change the right module/article
something like [this](http://www.icp-valves.com/es/productos)

I dont know if I explained myself well.

I used shaper helix 2 template

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check for some extensions here: http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/structure-a-navigation/menu-systems/accordion-menus

An advice... you better forget ajax to load the catalog because as it used on the example the product pages are missed by search engines, as spiders and crawlers doesn't execute javascript. Try to search for that domain... results don't have any product.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks I've been looking on how to do it with menus but I have 9 differents kind of products, i mean 9 different accordeons, do i have to do 9 menus? is there any other way to do it?